# How to find Libpng library used in android project

Tags: android-security

When I upload my project to google play store I am getting Libpng library error and app getting rejected. I am not sure where it been used. I been used many library might be among those. How can I find it out exactly where this been used.

Is there any way to force fully by pass this like (Just an example)-

```
resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.4.2'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the list of dependency you can run this from Gradle -> Dependencies

[image]

Then you can find out which library causing issue and you can exclude it like this

```
dependencies 
{
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:xx.0.+'
   compile ("com.xxx:xxx-commons:1.+") 
   {
       exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
   }
}
```

Comment: `dependencies` will only print the java/jar/aar lib dependencies, while `libpng` is a `c` library accessed via native functions!